# Running rails git cloned repo locally: How to handle gem errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eventmachine, git-clone, gemfile, gemfile.lock

All the time when I do a `git clone https://github.com/[REPO_NAME]` and then `cd` into the repo and run `bundle install` I get

> Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
> /Users/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby extconf.rb
> ```
>
> *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
>   the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
>   options.

And most of the time this has to do with an error occurring while installing `eventmachine`

Otherwise, all of the **rails app created by me can be ran locally** with no issues it just **do not work when I am trying to run locally git cloned app**.

I am just confused, I tried to change my ruby version, updated xcode and reset the gemfile.lock I just do not know whats wrong with my local environment.

Please I need some light as in what should I look into ? What should I check to make gem dependencies work when I am trying to run an app locally which is not created by me but that is a git cloned app?

Thanks a lot in advance to all the kind contributors.

**UPDATE:**

rvm -v:

```
rvm 1.26.10 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

rvm list:

```
rvm rubies

   ruby-2.1.2 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.1.3 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.5 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

which ruby:

```
/Users/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby
```

brew -v:

```
Homebrew 0.9.5
```

brew doctor:

```
otool: error: unable to find utility "otool", not a developer tool or in PATH
Error: Failure while executing: /usr/bin/otool -L /usr/bin/install_name_tool
```

Comment: r u switching to appropriate ruby version and rails version every time you clone a new repo in your local? and then running bundle install.

Comment: well the repo do not have any ruby version mentioned but I thought that by running bundle install it would set up the appropriate rails version. I know how to switch from one ruby -v to another but how so you switch rails version ?

Comment: the best way would be 'create a gemset for specific ruby version and rails version'.

Comment: For rails version check your gemfile from repo. It would be there.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this answer your question exactly. But it will help you for sure. So, please give it a try and check if the issue still exists.

```
Step 1: rvm use ruby-version # switch to specific ruby 
Step 2: rvm gemset create r4.2 # Create new gemset. Give name based on rails version. It will help you keep track of ruby and rails version together.
```

Then you can switch to specific ruby gemset using `rvm use` command.

```
Step 3: rvm use ruby-version@r4.2
```

Now do bundle install. And you will have separate wrappers for your project.

Now add two new file `.ruby-version` and `.ruby-gemset` in your project repo to avoid typing `rvm use` every time you `cd` in directory.

```
Content of `.ruby-version`:   
ruby-2.2.0 # ruby version respective to your project

Content of `.ruby-gemset`:  
r4.2 # gemset name
```

So, Now whenever you `cd` to your project directory. It will automatically switch to respective ruby version and rails version. Hence this way you can avoid conflict. And do `bundle install`.

Note: Add these two file to `.gitignore` file if you do not want to commit.

Comment: Hi hkumar I have followed what you suggested, How do I know what rails version should I use with the cloned repo ? In the gemfile I mentioned `ruby "2.1.3"` and `gem 'rails',  '4.2'`. I do not know how to mentioned the gemset name in the gemfile. Before I had an error with eventmachine now the problem is with installing Json (1.8.2).

Comment: I just ran `brew update` and then `sudo gem install rails` because brew doctor caused en error and it failed to download rails. However when I ran bundle update now the error is while installing ffi (1.9.8).

Comment: I am so confused and I have to admit nothing make sens to me regarding setting up the environment in that case. Otherwise everything works fine with my other rails projects. Should I reset the environement settings for this projects and if yes how? Thanks @hkumar .

Comment: @Antoine: To know rails version check your Gemfile from repo. As you said  , you have mentioned rails 4.2 then this is the version. You don't have to mention gemset name in gemfile. You need to create two new file .ruby-version and .ruby-gemset . And then do the bundle install.

Comment: Please follow the above instruction.

Comment: I have followed your instruction but I still get an error message: An error occurred while installing ffi (1.9.8), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.9.8'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: of course, gem install ffi -v '1.9.8' does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show me some of lists?
 Go to 'Terminal' 
run 'rvm -v'
run 'rvm list'
run 'which ruby'
run 'brew -v'
run 'brew doctor'

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. I have updated my question in order include what you asked for. I am looking forward to read you soon !